# Why does first version document show as minor version?

Tags: versioning

When I allow SharePoint 2013 to create major and minor versions, the first document uploaded shows up as a minor version. It has a decimal number instead of a whole number. Shouldn't it show up as a major version with a whole number?

However, when I only allow Major Versions, the document is uploaded as a Major Version.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. When minor versioning is used, the initial upload will be .1 and will continue to increment upward until the file is Published as a major version. At that point, it will be 1.0.

This is the draft versioning and publishing type scenario where you work on a document and publish it when it is finished.

Major versioning only does just that, increments major version numbers on every change of the document, no matter how small or insignificant. The notion of going from a 1.0 to a 2.0 usually implies some significant change. In this case, you can quickly go from 1.0 to 7.0, by rephrasing something, then fixing a typo, then later altering metadata.

Comment: SharePointNY - Be aware the minor draft version is around 500.  When the number magic number is hit, users will be unable to save additional changes to the file until a major version has been published.  I’ve run into this issue several times in the course of my career.  Users enable minor versioning without the understanding that files should be published at some point.

Comment: So when I check out the document that document will be the latest version, is this correct?
Thanks for you answer by the way.